# Is it possible to add a file to Google Cloud Storage from a url?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

On my php server I have a list of urls that point to large files (not locally stored). These files can be hundreds of Mb so I'm looking for the best way to add them to GCS without first saving them to my server. Is this possible or will I have to save each one then upload it to GCS?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention the list of urls that I have is managed programatically and changes often so any solution needs to be able to be implemented without manual interaction.

Answer (score 1):

If your urls are publicly reachable, you may be interested in the Transfer Service provided by Google Cloud Storage. You can provide a TSV file with a list of urls from where your files will be uploaded to the bucket of your choice. You can have a look at the service doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console) for further details.

Comment: I saw that but it lists the following things as requirements and I'm not sure I can get them without first downloading the files.

- The size of the object in bytes.
- The Base64-encoded MD5 hash of the object